# Use .ico from qrc in ToolButton icon.source

Tags: qt, qml

I'm trying to set a `.ico` from one of my resources to a ToolButton, but is only showing a black icon

Heres an example code:

```
ToolButton {
   id: btnEditFinish
   property url saveIcon: "qrc:/icons/save"
   icon.source: saveIcon
}
```

*Note*: qrc image is valid and it's a `.ico` with multiple sizes

```
<RCC>
<qresource prefix="/icons">
    <file alias="save">images/Save.ico</file>
</qresource>
</RCC>
```

Why this ain't working?

[image: Black icon]

Comment: How do I mark it as correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working. Had to add the *icon.color: 'transparent'* property.

According to [Qml ToolButton docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.11/qml-qtquick-controls2-abstractbutton.html#icon-prop), unless you explicity set icon.color to 'transparent', the icon itself will be filled with a color, apparently black, if property is not present.

A working example:

```
ToolButton {
      id: btnEditFinish
      icon.source: "qrc:/icons/save"
      icon.color: 'transparent'
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE RCC>
<RCC version="1.0">
    <qresource prefix="/icons">
        <file alias="Save.ico">icons/Save.ico</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

Icon file must be placed in (current dir from rcc file): **./icons/Save.ico**

Set icon as **":/icons/Save.ico"** or **"qrc:/icons/Save.ico"**.